# Selenium: Having trouble right clicking element using contextClick

Tags: selenium

I have been running through this over and over and can not figure out where i am going wrong.  I have the following code to right click an element and then on the popup menu move down twice and click the second menu option.

```
    System.out.println("HELLO TESTING THAT THIS IS SEEN");
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.contextClick(firstRow).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    confirmDeleteYes.click();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(policySearchField));
```

ignore the system.out.print line as its there to make sure i was getting to this function. It appears to either be failing right after the action.contextclick(firstrow ) line.  I see in logs that it is searching for a confirmation delete button that is shown once i click the second second option in the context menu which is a delete button.

When watching this run i do not see the contexct menu popup.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

replace this:

```
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.contextClick(firstRow).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

with:

```
    new Actions(driver).contextClick(firstRow).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN).perform();
```

and now i am able to see the context menu come up and click the button i am trying to click